# Exchange Dynamic Distribution Group RecipientFilter not excluding department

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Trying to set a dynamic distribution group filter using:

```
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "Employees" -RecipientFilter {((RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (-not(Department -eq 'HR')) -and (Title -ne $null)) -or ((RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'MailContact') -and (Alias -like 'group1_*' -or Alias -like 'group2_*'))}
```

Which should create two filter groups:

1. UserMailboxes where department attribute is not 'HR' and title attribute is not empty
2. MailContacts where the alias is like 'group1_*' or 'group2_*'

and if the object matches either of the groups then include them in they dynamic distribution group.

All the filters are working as expected except for the `(-not(Department -eq 'HR'))`. I've tried several variations including:

- `Department -ne 'HR'`
- `-and -not (Department -eq 'HR')`
- Replacing the `{` with `"`
- Reorganizing the filter groups
- Regrouping the filter groups

```
Get-AdObject -Filter 'Department -eq "HR"'
```

returns the user objects that I'm trying to exclude, so I'm assuming it is something to do with the OPath syntax. `Department` is in the documentation for [filterable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/recipientfilter-properties?view=exchange-ps). Does anyone know how to get this exclusion to work?